# Need help in php mysql statement which has "and" and range

Tags: php, mysql

I am want to write a php mysql query which includes `and` and `range` condition.
In the screen shot you can see the field of the table called `search`. The fields with same name are the range. I want select query and it should include all the fields and their appropriate range.

The names of the fields are `shape1`,`shape2`(it is range from `shape1` to `shape2`) etc and it goes on.

The query should be like this

```
select * from search where unique_id='$unique_id && (carat1='$carat1' between carat2='carat2') &&...
```

and there are other field too like `cut` and `shape`, all in one query. I am inserting value in to the database directly from android in `json` format.  My problem is that i don't know proper format.

Please help me

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: use and condition and for range use between in sql

Comment: can you tell me proper format, this is my query in improper format "select * from search where unique_id='$unique_id && (carat1='$carat1' between carat2='carat2') &&..." there are more field like shape, cut etc and all of them should be in one query

Comment: can you paste your whole query in your question so we will give you an appropriate format in sql

Comment: shape is number or string

Comment: all of them are string except carat and unique id is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go like this (an example)

```
select * from search 
where unique_id= 10
and carat1 between 1 and 10
and shape1 between 1 and 10
and cut1 between 1 and 10
```

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to run the SQL from PHP script then the format will be different like below (if the column is type integer like `unique_id` then don't put `'` while replacing value. For string type replace with `'` like `carat`)

```
Select * from search 
where unique_id = $unique_id
and carat between '$carat1' and '$carat2' 
and color between '$color1' and '$color2' 
and shape between '$shape1' and '$shape2'
```

Comment: is this correct format??Select * from search where unique_id = '$unique_id' and  carat between carat1='$carat1' and carat2='$carat2' and color between color1='$color1' and color2 = '$color2' and shape between shape1='$shape1 and shape2='$shape2';

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni, yes it's indeed but what syntax/format you are looking for. if you are going run this query directly in mysql then absolutely correct format but if you are trying to run it through PHp script then not since you will have to replace the values in condition.

Comment: thanks. If the values of color, shape are string then will the above format work??

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni, yes it will work (I mean the one I have given in my answer). Why don't try and see if it works at all or not?

Comment: I am passing data from android device to my php server using JSON but problem is that the android side is not ready so don't have any way to test it yet

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni, that's alright. AFAIK, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Example usage of between in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM search 
WHERE unique_id = 200 AND
carat BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

Note that the AND that follows BETWEEN is used to indicate the range (1,5) and is not a logical AND operator.

Comment: what about this format select * from search where unique_id='$unique_id && (carat1='$carat1' between carat2='carat2') && " there are more field too like cut, shape all in one query

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will help you

```sql
SELECT * FROM search
    WHERE unique_id = $unique_id AND
          carat between $carat1 AND $carat2 AND
          color like '%".$color1."%' AND
          color like  '%".$color2."%' AND
          shape like '%".$shape1."%' AND
          shape like '%".$shape2."%'
```

Comment: this one??Select * from search where unique_id = '$unique_id' and  carat between carat1='$carat1' and carat2='$carat2' and color between color1='$color1' and color2 = '$color2' and shape between shape1='$shape1 and shape2='$shape2';